# How to open local filesystem links in Google Chrome?

Tags: kubuntu, google-chrome, filesystem

In our work intranet I get served links in the form:

```
file:///home/bruni/Documents/
```

(These links lead to a mountpoint on my local filesystem.)

Is it possible to click on these links and open them in Dolphin?

I am using google chrome on KUbuntu 17.10.

In Firefox I have found an add-on ([Local Filesystem Links](https://github.com/feinstaub/webextension_local_filesystem_links)) that does exactly this (though it strangely opens the links in Nautilus and not Dolphin).

On Chrome every add-on I tried seems to be written for windows. Does anybody know of a similar solution for Chrome under Kubuntu?

PS: To clarify. One solution would be something like [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/local-explorer-file-manag/eokekhgpaakbkfkmjjcbffibkencdfkl) for Ubuntu.

Comment: this looks like a Samba-Share and you should be able to open `smb://home/bruni/Documents` in Doplhin

Comment: @derHugo Indeed it is a **mounted** share (though not samba), but that has nothing to do with my question. It is a local link and I am able to open it in dolphin (just copy file:///home/bruni/Documents/). I want to be able to click on the link in chrome and open the locally mounted share, without having to copy paste link location. This is possible in Firefox as described above with an add-on.

Comment: I haven't got Chrome, but Chromium-Browser, and it can browse the local file system by itself without plugin. - *What happens with Chrome? Does it work, but not as convenient as if Dolphin would be plugged in? Or is nothing happening?* - (For me Chromium-Browser and Firefox behave in similar ways). You do actually open the locally mounted share, when seeing it in Chrome (if you see it like I see it in Chromium-Browser). Or maybe I don't understand.

Comment: @sudodus Nothing happens when I click on the link in Chrome.  In Firefox, with the plugin, Nautilus (now called Files) opens the location.

Comment: @sidodus To avoid misunderstandings: when I write the address in the chrome addressbar I also can access the location in chrome, but when I click on the link nothing happens. I would like to be able to use the links as in Firefox.

Comment: I think I understand now.  It might be a security feature, that does not allow access like that. Maybe there is a setting to turn it on/off. Or is there a right-click option, that would allow you to succeed? (I don't know how I could test it in a relevant way.)

Comment: Try to copy that into address bar in dolphin

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Copying works as I have described. I would like a way for the link to work.

Comment: It might be a security feature, that does not allow access like that. Maybe there is a setting to turn it on/off. Have you looked into the settings menus in Chrome?

Comment: Yes, I did not find anything there. I found references in the net to such a setting in chromium, but they were quite old and as I understood no longer applicable.

Comment: I could nоt understand where are these links. It it a web page with links inside?

Comment: @pa4080 Yes, a webpage on our intranet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is due to the security policies of the web browsers. More detailed explanation is provided [here](https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/opening-links-to-local-files-file/16449/7). The good news is that there is a couple of available extensions that could solve this problem. For example:

- For **Firefox** prior to Firefox Quantum:

  - The extension [LocalLink](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/locallink/) will add an entry (called *Open Link in Local Context*) into the right click context menu.
  - The extension [Local Filesystem Links](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/local-filesystem-links/) will open these links (`file:///`) into the default File Explorer - in my case it is Nautilus.
- For **Chrome/Chromium**:

  - The extension [Enable local file links](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/enable-local-file-links/nikfmfgobenbhmocjaaboihbeocackld?hl=en-US) will cause the browser to work with the local links (`file:///`) as if they are 'normal' links.

---

While the extension *Local Filesystem Links* could serve within Firefox according to the question's requirements, I couldn't found an analogical extension for Chrome/Chromium. But I found the following workaround.

**1.** Add the extension [Open in Firefox](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/open-in-firefox/lmeddoobegbaiopohmpmmobpnpjifpii) to Chrome/Chromium. Follow [the installation guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bB4Bj_APg4g) and setup the extension.

**2.** Once the extension works properly, right click on its icon and go to the *Options* menu. Fill in `/usr/bin/dolphin` for "Path to executable" and Save.

**3.** Now you could open these links via the option *Open Link in Firefox Browser* from the right click context menu.

---

Here is a demo how the mentioned extensions for Chrome work (together):

- [Enable local file links](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/enable-local-file-links/nikfmfgobenbhmocjaaboihbeocackld?hl=en-US)
- [Open in Firefox](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/open-in-firefox/lmeddoobegbaiopohmpmmobpnpjifpii)

[image]

Comment: I think so too (but I have not Chrome, so I am not sure). Let us hope that @Bruni can make it work.

Answer (score 2):

If @pa4080 approach is what you want to follow, use the "External Application Button" extension (from the same developer) so that you can rename the context-menu item properly.

The extension is available for Firefox, Opera, and Chrome:
https://add0n.com/external-application-button.html

Comment: Very nice shot!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative that works for **Firefox Quantum** (though technically not answering the question)

Edit the file [prefs.js](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Firefox_:_Issues_:_Links_to_Local_Pages_Don%27t_Work#Firefox_1.5.2C_SeaMonkey_1.0_and_newer) in your firefox profile folder under ~/.mozilla/firefox to include

> user_pref("capability.policy.policynames", "localfilelinks");
>   user_pref("capability.policy.localfilelinks.sites",
>   "http://www.example.com");
>   user_pref("capability.policy.localfilelinks.checkloaduri.enabled",
>   "allAccess");

replacing www.example.com for the site you want to include this functionality. Then you will also have to use the "External Application Button" extension as described in @Belaviyo 's answer (https://add0n.com/external-application-button.html)

Answer (score 1):

I just discovered this [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/local-explorer-file-manag/eokekhgpaakbkfkmjjcbffibkencdfkl) recently. It can bypass Chrome security boundaries. Take a look and see if it works for you.

Comment: "- Currently it works only on Windows, we would build Mac OS and Linux version if we got high volume of requests."